# Laravel eloquent many to many returns empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

So i'm trying to get my head around using eloquent for many to many relationships in my application.

I have three tables as followed

```
   user
    +----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
    +----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
    | first_name     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | last_name      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | email          | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
    | password       | varchar(60)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | remember_token | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | created_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    | updated_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    | active         | enum('yes','no') | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | last_login     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    +----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

    user_has_address
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | address_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | users_id   | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

    address
    +---------------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type                       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
    +---------------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | id            | int(10) unsigned           | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
    | name_number   | varchar(45)                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | first_line    | varchar(45)                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | second_line   | varchar(45)                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | town_city     | varchar(45)                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | state_country | varchar(45)                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | post_zip      | varchar(45)                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | type          | enum('delivery','billing') | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | created_at    | timestamp                  | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    | updated_at    | timestamp                  | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    | deleted_at    | timestamp                  | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    +---------------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

in my user repository i have the following

```
namespace App\Libraries\Repositories\Core\Users;

use Schema;
use App\Models\Core\User;
use Bosnadev\Repositories\Eloquent\Repository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class UserRepository extends Repository
{
    public function getUsersAddresses()
    {
        return $this->userModel->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Bundle\Addresses\Address','App\Models\Bundle\Addresses\UserHasAdress','id','address_id');
    }
}
```

Im returned an object that shows parent and related classes but im not actually returned my users address. Is there something im missing?

Comment: To do a standard many to many (i.e. a user has many addresses, and an address belongs to many users) you use "belongs to many" not "has many through". Also, the relationship methods are best used on the models themselves, not the repository classes, as you get the extra Laravel magic (i.e. you could use `$this->userModel->addresses`) as if it's a property.

Answer (score 1):

Alexrussell made some good points in his comment that you could possibly address, however I believe your immediate problem is a missing `->get()` at the end of your return line.

Without it, you would be required to call your method like:

`$repository->getUsersAddresses()->get();`

As `hasManyThrough` will return an instance of `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough` not the actual results

For reference:
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.html

Note in the example here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

The example usage includes a get(): `$roles = App\User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();`

Hope this helps

Comment: In my case the get() method helped me to resolve the problem.